# Can I move the main breaker box to inside a small bathroom?

Tags: plumbing, electrical-distribution, breaker-box

This is very similar to the "electric box over sump" question.

I'm finishing the basement, which includes upgrading the breaker box and moving it to a more suiting location.

I would really like to move it inside a small bathroom I am building underneath the basement steps (box would be moved about 10 feet splicing the 4/0 cable).

The box would be embedded in the 2x4 walls I'm putting up against the basement block, and above a macerating toilet.  I can make sure the toilet water supply and waste are outside the "protected" spaces of the box.

I guess the other concern is if the toilet is a work obstruction.  It has no water closet, just the bowl.  I kind of chuckle because the toilet lid would make a great place to set your tools if you do have to swap out a breaker or something.  The toilet could actually be unbolted and lifted out if needed for projects that might require better access to the box.

I know codes vary.  Is there a general rule for this?  It seems very often boxes are put over sumps and I believe this to be less of an issue.

Answer (score 3):

According to National Electrical Code,  overcurrent protection cannot be in bathrooms. So no, you cannot put the panel in the bathroom.

> ## National Electrical Code 2014
>
> ### Chapter 2 Wiring and Protection
>
> #### Article 240 Overcurrent Protection
>
> **240.24 Location in or on Premises.**
>
> **(E) Not Located in Bathrooms.** In dwelling units, dormitories, and guest rooms or guest suites, overcurrent devices, other than supplementary overcurrent protection, shall not be located in bathrooms.